# Will be there an OneDrive SDK for tvOS in the near future?

Tags: cocoapods, tvos, onedrive

I wanna develop a tvOS app that is able to connect to atlas one One Drive folder. If I use the CocoaPod it tells me, that this version of the SDK is not targeted to work with tvOS.

Will be there an OneDrive SDK for tvOS in the near future?

I'm not alone, the [related Github issue](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-ios/issues/71) got at least one thumb up.

Answer (score 0):

[OneDrive API](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) is primarily JSON over HTTP. This should be straighforward enough for you to consume using normal HTTP calls.

If your app's competitive edge relies on accessing OneDrive (for example, you're competing with Arq Backup), you'd probably be better off writing your own network calls using `NSURLConnection` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It would be great to ship it like other apps using the SDK. No OAuth hassle etc. Maybe a MSFT member has a roadmap that contains a planned release date.

Comment: OAuth will be challenging since there isn't any Web View on tvOS SDK (not officially at least). Either you have a complementary app on iOS which does OAuth or roll out your own HTML renderer and solve the awkward password input problem yourself.